# Group By Dinstinct in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pandas-groupby, distinct

I Have Script Like This in Pandas :

```
dfmi['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(dfmi['Time'], format='%H:%M:%S')
dfmi['hours'] = dfmi['Time'].dt.hour
sum_dh = dfmi.groupby(['Date','hours']).agg({'Amount': 'sum', 'Price':'sum'})
dfdhsum = pd.DataFrame(sum_dh)
dfdhsum.columns = ['Amount', 'Gas Sales']
dfdhsum
```

And the output :

[image]

I want Sum Distinct Group BY and the final result is like This :

[image]

How its pandas code solution ??

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what you want to exactly but this instruction will sum hours , amount ans gas sales for each date

```
 dfmi.groupby("Date").agg({'hours': 'sum', 'Amount': 'sum','Gas Sales':'sum})
```